# Can you submit a new app for review while having a version in "pending developer release" state

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Have an app that is currently available. A recent version was submitted and approved and in the the "pending developer release" until we meet our launch date. However, there are a few bugs we'd like to fix. We don't want to remove/or reject the current binary that was approved because we may not have enough time before our launch to go through the review process again. The question is can we submit a new version of the app for review while keeping the "approved" version in the "pending developer release" state.?

Answer (score 10):

No you can't. Your app has to be in the "ready for sale" state before you can create a new version and resubmit.